# Which windows work with which automated window openers?

Tags: windows

I need to replace all the windows in a house. In planning to do so, I'd like to preserve the option of eventually (not necessarily simultaneous with the new window installation) installing some kind of automated window opener like [this one](http://www.window-openers.com/sliding_sash_window_opener.html) so that when home-automation technology is more fully mature, I can add some kind of window opening/shutting device that would communicate wirelessly with a home automation server and allow me to do things like open all the windows in the house from a remote location via my Android phone or tablet.

But it's clear to me that not all windows work with all window openers.

So does anyone know a good resource with a comprehensive list of automated/electric window openers and which windows they function properly with? Or perhaps a list of windows and which automated/electric window openers they work with?

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to do this? Home automation technology is a terrible idea IMHO. The stuff is expensive, there are no standards to make things work together, and it will all break in a few years and have to be replaced. Having been in many houses with this kind of equipment in them, I cannot honestly say any of them really added value to the house, made their owners' lives any easier, or saved anyone any time at all. Do you really have so many windows that you actually open and close frequently enough that walking around your house to do it yourself is a hassle?

Comment: There are more than 40 windows in this house. The house was built before modern cooling systems existed, so it was designed to be  cooled with windows, and it's a good design, but yes, I imagine it would take 10-20 minutes to open all those windows by hand. Automation tech may not now be adequate for a task like this, but I have no doubt that it will eventually become as much a standard as residential electricity is now. And probably even within the next 10-20 years. The house is ~90 years old already, and the windows are original. I'd rather not replace the windows again in the next 90 years.

Comment: Sounds like better insulation would really help you. Replacing 40 windows is not likely to be cost-effective, but window technology is better than ever. In 90 years, the next inhabitants may want to replace them anyway because of advances in technology.